# Destruir session quando alterar perfil no mobile e afetar o pc

Tags: php, pdo

Olá,

Como faço para resolver o problema de quando alguem editar o perfil no mobile e ao mesmo tempo estiver logado no pc, não der erro php como 'Undefined variable' no pc pois os dados já não são os mesmo do mobile..

Por exemplo, o login é william ai eu fiz o login no celular e no pc, ai eu editei meu login no celular para curruwilla e salvei, ai no pc está como william ainda dando erro

Aqui ta as session para recuperar os dados dos usuarios:
Como posso melhorar isso para selecionar os usuario pelo ID para quando eu nao alterar o username ou password não der erro ?

```
if(isset($_SESSION['useronnected']) && (isset($_SESSION['passconnected']))){
$userLogged = $_SESSION['useronnected'];
$passLogged = $_SESSION['passconnected'];

// seleciona o usuario logado
    $selectLogged = "SELECT * from users WHERE user=:userLogged AND password=:passLogged";
    try {
        $result = $conexao->prepare($selectLogged);
        $result->bindParam('userLogged', $userLogged, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam('passLogged', $passLogged, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->execute();
        $count = $result->rowCount();

        if($count =1){
            $loop = $result->fetchAll();
            foreach ($loop as $show) {
                $idLogged = $show['id'];
                $nameLogged = $show['name'];
                $userLogged = $show['user'];
                $passwordLogged = $show['password'];
                $emailLogged = $show['email'];
                $levelLogged = $show['level'];
            }
        }
    }catch (PDOException $e){ echo $e;}
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['useronnected']) && (!isset($_SESSION['passconnected']))){
    $levelLogged = 0;
}
```

E aqui ta o login:

```
if(isset($_POST['loggin'])){
    // RECUPERAR DADOS DO FORM
    $user        = trim(strip_tags($_POST['user']));
    $password    = trim(strip_tags($_POST['password']));

    //SELECIONAR BANCO DE DADOS
    $select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY user=:user AND BINARY password=:password";

    try {
        $result = $conexao->prepare($select);
        $result->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->execute();
        $count = $result->rowCount();

        if($count>0){
            $user    = $_POST['user'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $_SESSION['useronnected'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['passconnected'] = $password;
            header("Location: page.php");
        }else{
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Erro ao logar!</strong> Os dados estão incorretos.
            </div>';
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54250/discussion-on-question-by-william-alvares-destruir-session-quando-alterar-perfil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma refatoração do código, e abaixo uma explicação das mudanças e seus motivos:

```
$levelLogged = 0;
if( isset($_SESSION['userId'] ) {
    $query = 'SELECT * from users WHERE id=:userId';
    try {
        $result = $conexao->prepare( $query );
        $result->bindParam( 'userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $result->execute();
        if( $result->rowCount() == 1 ){
            $dados = $result->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
            $nameLogged  = $dados ['name'];
            $userLogged  = $dados ['user'];
            $levelLogged = $dados ['level'];
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e){ echo $e;}
}
```

- passamos o $levelLogged para cima, pois se qualquer coisa não funcionar na *query* ao DB, já garantimos que o usuário não vai ter privilégios na página.
- trocamos a verificação pelo Id do usuário, pois assim trabalhamos independentemente do nome deste, os outros dados são recuperados do BD.
- Não há necessidade de `fetchAll` e nem de *loop*, pois estamos recuperando apenas uma linha de dados.

Mas note: isto só deve ser feito nas páginas em que os dados realmente forem servir no corpo da requisição, senão basta usar o nome e o Id.

Para que o login funcione com o código acima, segue a refatoração do 2º bloco que você postou:

```
if(isset($_POST['loggin'])){
    $user        = trim( $_POST['user'] );
    $password    = trim( $_POST['password'] );

    $select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=:user AND BINARY password=:password";

    try {
        $result = $conexao->prepare($select);
        $result->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->execute();
        $count = $result->rowCount();

        if( $count == 1 ){ [userId'] = $user;
            $dados = $result->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
            $_SESSION['userId']    = $dados['name'];
            $_SESSION['userName']  = $dados['name'];
            $_SESSION['userLevel'] = $dados['level'];
            header("Location: page.php");
            die();
        }else{
            $_SESSION['userId']     = 0;
            $_SESSION['userName']   = '';
            $_SESSION['userLevel']  = 0;

            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Erro ao logar!</strong> Os dados estão incorretos.
            </div>';
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

Aqui mudamos o seguinte:

- Acrescentamos o `userId` na session, que é a base da identidade do usuário. Aliás, o nome ID do campo vem de identidade, que é o conceito de informação imutável. O usuário pode trocar de nome, de sexo, de endereço, mas em teoria o Id será sempre o mesmo.
- o `userLevel` e o `userName` já são pegos e guardados na *session*, em vez de precisar requisitar do DB em todas as páginas. Assim, o primeiro bloco que você postou só será necessário em operações mais complexas, que dependam destes dados atualizados. Em outras partes, basta usar o *session*. Numa mudança de nome, a sessão aberta ficará com o nome antigo até fechar.
- mudamos o teste do count para `== 1`, pois se tiver mais que 1 usuário com as mesmas credenciais no DB, algo está errado.
- caso a transação não seja bem sucedida, estamos zerando os dados da *session* "na marra".
- **importante usarmos o `die()`** depois de header de redirect, (ou `exit()`), pois sem ele,o usuário recebe os dados da página, e só depois é redirecionado. Normalmente não vemos isso pelo fato de o redirect ser rápido, mas nada garante que ele vai acontecer ou que a informação não vá ser interpretada antes do redirect.
- foi removido o BINARY do username, pois normalmente maiúsculas e minúsculas são importantes apenas na senha. Isso é só para mostrar como alternativa, mas você deve adequar ao que entende ser correto no seu sistema.

Insistindo na observação feita anteriormente: usando o 2º bloco da forma que fizemos (ajustando para o seu caso real, claro), não precisamos fazer a busca no DB com o 1o bloco a todo o momento, pois a *session* já terá os dados fundamentais. Entendendo este conceito, você vai saber quando é hora de revisar o DB, e quando pode usar os dados de sessão.

Comment: @William sua pergunta foi [reaberta pela comunidade](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/103877/revisions), então postei um resumo do que já tinha respondido nos comentários. Se for o caso, depois vou dando uma incrementada nela com mais detalhes. Os comentários eu vou apagando depois, pra nao ficar bagunça demais na pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

Se você grava os dados do usuário na sessão, esse problema vai acontecer todas as vezes que você abrir mais de uma sessão para o mesmo usuário (seja PC + mobile, seja PC + PC, etc).

Para resolver isso, existem três formas.

1ª) Você grava **apenas** o ID do usuário na sessão e faz requisição dos demais dados ao banco em todas as suas requisições.

2ª) Você cria um botão para ATUALIZAR dados para trazer os dados novos do banco.

3ª) Você utiliza comunicação via socket para atualização *real time* (instantânea). Essa forma vai te dar mais trabalho, mas te abrirá também novos caminhos. Pesquise sobre Ratchet para implementá-la.

Comment: Gostaria que os prezados comentassem o voto contra, para que eu possa aprimorar meu conhecimento ou corrigir qualquer eventual texto mal explicado.

Comment: Ok, Bacco, muito obrigado pela dica. Como vc resolveria este problema? Pode nos ajudar?

Comment: Se for alguma coisa que eu entenda, posso tentar ajudar. Como eu resolveria qual problema, o que eu comentei antes, ou o do autor da pergunta? No 2o caso, postei umas recomendaçoes, que eu tinha comentado pra ele. No 1o caso, nao sei se alguma das coisas que eu tinha comentado poderia ser o motivo de alguma negativa (mas eu postei depois que a resposta já estava negativada, e o placar nao mudou depois disso) Edit: a própria pergunta do autor estava com -4, mas depois que ele deu uma elaborada já teve 2 positivos. Em pontuação compensa, pois cada positivo vale 10, cada negativo custa só 2.